# Error compilation with React styled-components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, compiler-errors, styled-components, react-props

I connect global styles via CreateGlobalStyle but gives an errors.

[example error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehKnm.png)

I have 3 files

GlobalResets:

```
import {createGlobalStyle} from 'styled-components';
import { Color } from './colors';

const GlobalResets = createGlobalStyle`
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;

    background: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }

  body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    background-color: ${Color.BLACK};
  }

  button,
  input,
  select {
    font: inherit;
  }

  a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  ol,
  ul {
    list-style: none;
  }  
`;

export { GlobalResets }
```

GlobalColors code:

```
import {createGlobalStyle} from 'styled-components';
enum Color {
    BLACK = `var(--color-black)`,
    LIGHT_BROWN = `var(--color-light-brown)`,
    BROWN = `var(--color-brown)`,
    BLUE = `var(--color-blue)`,
    LIGHT_GREEN = `var(--color-light-green)`,
    GREEN = `var(--color-green)`,
    BEIGE = `var(--color-beige)`,
    WHITE = `var(--color-white)`,
    GRAY = `var(--color-gray)`,
    RED = `var(--color-red)`,
}

const GlobalColors = createGlobalStyle`
  :root {
    --color-black: #000000;
    --color-light-brown: #DEAD8D;
    --color-brown: #C08332;
    --color-blue: #3F51B5;
    --color-light-green: #8BC34A;
    --color-green: #2E7D32;
    --color-beige: #FFCC80;
    --color-white: #F5F5F5;
    --color-gray: #D7CCC8;
    --color-red: #D32F2F;
  }
`;

export {Color, GlobalColors}
```

APP

```
import {GlobalResets} from "../../tokens/resets";
import {GlobalColors} from "../../tokens/colors";

const App = (): JSX.Element => (
    <>
        <GlobalResets />
        <GlobalColors />
    </>
)

export default App
```

Install latest styled-components and @types/styles-components but the errors don't go away

example error

> TS2740: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'TemplateStringsArray': raw, length, concat, join, and 20 more.
>
> const App = (): JSX.Element => (
>
> <GlobalResets />
>
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> <GlobalColors />
>
> )

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue after running the yarn command to install dependencies without a lock file. As a result, my styled-components package upgraded from v6.0.0-rc.1 to v6.0.0-rc.6. To confirm the version in your project, you can check your package-lock.json or yarn.lock file. Search for "styled-components," and the second line will indicate the version.

Unfortunately, I couldn't determine the root cause of the problem, so I reverted back to the previous working version in my package.json file:

```json
"styled-components": "6.0.0-rc.1",
```

I intend to investigate this issue further in the near future, but for now, this solution will suffice.

If you choose to adhere to this workaround, don't forget to delete your package-lock.json or yarn.lock file, as well as the node_modules directory before running your package install command.